# Follow each pixel brightness in set of images (Memory constrained)

Tags: image-processing, import, parallelization, memory

I have a set of 2700 consecutive png images (8bit, 2048*2048 pixels).

I would like to **visualize the intensity variation of each pixel vs. image number**.

Here is an example of 10 images: http://goo.gl/52McV3

At first I wanted to store the intensity of each pixel in each image into an array. Unfortunately the code below does not work properly. What am I doing wrong?

```
ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[imageDir], "Directory"], 
   Dynamic[imageDir]}];
SetDirectory[imageDir];
fNames = FileNames["*.png"];
numFiles = Length[fNames];

SetSharedVariable[pixelIntensity];

pixelIntensity = Array[0 &, {2048, 2048, numFiles , 1}];

ParallelTable[

  image = Import[fNames[[i]]];

  ParallelTable[
   pixelIntensity[[r, c, i]] = 
    ImageData[ImageTake[image, {r, r}, {c, c}]],
   {r, 1, 2048}, {c, 1, 2048}
   ],

  {i, 1, numFiles}

  ];
```

I have RAM problems when many images (2700) have to be processed

Comment: So you want to visualize 4194304 curves of 2700 points each? ...

Comment: **These images are taken with a CMOS chip which has a few (some 1000s) pixels that have after calibration (reset to 0 brightness) still non-zero brightness values**. Their amplifier are not working properly. 
**I would like especially to find these pixels (their coordinates)** and investigate their brightness variation.

Comment: I think you'll find `Import[]` swamps the time of everything else. If you want to load the data just do something like this: `Transpose[ImageData@Import[#] & /@ fNames, {3, 2, 1}]`

Comment: @mrz could you comment on the performance of the different approaches  offered in the answers for your particular data?  There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. Better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part tomorrow

Comment: Excuse me, I had to do some other work last week and could not continue the work on the asked question ... I will try to do it in the next days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data

```
FileNames["*.png"]
(* {"image_01.png", "image_02.png", "image_03.png", \
"image_04.png", "image_05.png", "image_06.png", "image_07.png", \
"image_08.png", "image_09.png", "image_10.png"} *)
```

### All at once

If there are no memory constraints, you can load all in a single array (read below for other cases).

```
data = ImageData[Import[#], "Byte"] & /@ FileNames["image_*.png"];

MinMax@Flatten[data]
(* {0, 97}*)

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[data[[All, x, y]], PlotRange -> {0, 100}]
 , {x, 1, Length[data[[1]]], 1}
 , {y, 1, Length[data[[1, 1]]], 1}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### Efficient memory use

Loading data only for the requested pixel coordinates, by taking advantage of the options of [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) that allow loading only specific parts of components using `Import["file.png", {"Data", row, column}]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also using [Memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html), so if you call for the same data more than once, no work is repeated.

#### For a single coordinate pair

```
xyd[x_Integer, y_Integer] := 
 xyd[x, y] = 
  ParallelMap[Import[#, {"Data", x, y}] &, FileNames["image_*.png"]]

ListPlot[xyd[822, 920]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

#### For a list of coordinates

```
xyld[list_] :=
 xyld[list] =
  Transpose@ParallelMap[
    Diagonal@Import[#, {"Data", list[[All, 1]], list[[All, 2]]}] &
    , FileNames["*.png"]
    ]
```

Comment: This is great ... but I have RAM problems when many images (2700) have to be processed

Comment: Thank you ... I will try that tomorrow and inform you.

Comment: I have edited considerably the answer, please let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: My experience has been it is actually faster to import a whole image and extract the required part ( `Import[file,"Data"][[row,col]]` ) than to use `Import`'s subelement feature..

Comment: @george2079 Thanks for your comment. What would that be? I guess it depends on how much RAM there is available in relation with file size. I would expect that `Import` should offer a lower level approach that avoids loading unnecessary data, but as always, the devil in in the details.

Comment: I implemented your code and it works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mrz did you get a chance to compare performance of the different approaches? I'm curious about the comments by george2079

Comment: I am using now a lot your "All at once"-solution, since my recent images are relatively small. The code works perfect and you helped me a lot. From the brightness variations of single pixels I was able to find some unexpected resonance frequencies of our CMOS camera pixels, which are probably due to the electronics. I will also try out to compare with the info by george2079 and let you know. Please excuse me that I did not immediately respond.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I'd do: You say most of the pixels are dark, and thus uninteresting, but some of them are bright. So I'd start by summing all images up to find the "bad" pixels:

```
files = FileNames[
   "*.png"];

totalBrightness = 0.0;
Monitor[Do[
   totalBrightness = ImageData[Import[f]] + totalBrightness, {f, 
    files}], f];

meanBrightness = totalBrightness/Length[files];    

brightestPixels = Reverse[Sort[Flatten[meanBrightness]]][[;; 100]];

ListLinePlot[brightestPixels, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Top 100 brightest pixel values (mean over all images)"]
```

[image]

Then you can load the images a second time and extract the pixel values for these positions:

```
brightestPixelLocations = 
  Position[meanBrightness, #][[1]] & /@ brightestPixels;

Monitor[pixelValues = 
   Table[Extract[ImageData[Import[f]], brightestPixelLocations], {f, 
     files}], f];
```

and plot them any way you like:

```
ListLinePlot[pixelValues\[Transpose][[;; 10]], 
 PlotLabel -> "Top 10 brightest pixels", PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Image Index", "Brightness"}]
```

[image]

```
ArrayPlot[pixelValues, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, ImageSize -> 800, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Image index", "Top 100 Pixels"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution for picking the bright pixels ... it would be good to be able to a accept more than one answer as a (different) solution ... unfortunately this not possible.